# How to find a subset of size k such that the minimum distance between values is maximum

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

Suppose I have a sorted array which contains `n` integers.
How do I find subset of size `k` such that the minimum distance between all pairs of integers in the subset is maximized, I mean they are at maximal distance.

example: `array a[]={1,2,6,7,10}` and `k=3`,
`subset = {1,6,10}`, the minimum distance is 4 between 10 and 6.
Wrong subsets:
`{1,7,10}` , minimum distance is `3`
`{1,2,6}` , minimum distance is `1`

My first thought was to get all the combinations in the size of k, then calculate the distance of each one. But the time complexity would be O(n!), and the interviewer doesn't like it. Dynamic Programming is the hint he gave me, but I still have no idea.

He suggested that I can start from a[0], find a[0]+*x*=Y also in the array... and then Y+*x* and so on k-1 times, also kth element will be a[n-1], but I couldn't get him. I don't know why there must be such a *x*, like in the example above, the correct answer is {1,6,10}, the distance between 1 and 6 is 5, and it's 4 between 6 and 10, then what should *x* be?

Comment: This feels like a homework question. Can you [edit] to include your attempted approach? "I'm clueless" to me seems like you haven't tried or even approached the problem. We're not here to do homework problems for you.

Comment: If you would like help, try editing your question and posting how you might try to solve it in a brute force approach.  You have to show some effort or it might be closed.  Does it have to be dynamic programming?

Comment: The problem with these interview questions - they are either after "what is the edge of your program trick knowledge" or the "how do you solve a problem you don't know?"  The former is boring, and the later, if you already know it just provokes *another* question in this vein.

Comment: I am not an expert at dynamic programming techniques by any means, but it does seem similar to the subset sum problem: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/

Comment: To be frankly honest I don't understand this question at all the way it is worded.  It might be because it is late and my brain turned off. My only suggestion to you with dynamic programming is try to identify if you can break it into smaller problems that can somehow feed into the larger answer.  Then try to think how you might solve this recursively using the previous recursive calls return value to feed your answer.  Then you can try to figure out how you can memoize the sub problems into a single or two dimensional array so that as you progress through the table you can refer to previous.

Answer (score -1):

For some given lists and sizes, it may have many correct answers.

I would try a greedy algorithm instead of backtracking: Given an sub-selection, if one wants to extend it to an extra element, one simply have to select the new one, since the maximum of minimal distances can only decrease as the number of elements increases. Complexity: O(k*n*n), which is a better than O(n!).

If you ignore special cases (size > list.size, etc.):

```
List<Int> maxmin(List<Int> l, int size)
{
   Int head = l.subList(0, 1);
   List<Int> tail = l.subList(1, l.size());
   more(head, tail, size-1);
}

private List<Int> more(List<Int> selected, List<Int> available, int size)
{
   if(size == 0) return selected;
   else
   {
      int max = maxByMin(available, selected);
      selected.add(max);
      available.remove(max);
      return more(selected, available, size-1);
   }
}

private int maxByMin(List<Int> candidates, List<Int> elements)
{
   int maxMin = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   int maxVal = candidates(0);

   for(int candidate : candidates)
   {
      int minDist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

      for(int element : elements)
      {
         int dist = math.abs(candidate, element);
         if(dist < minDist)
         {
             minDist = dist;
         }
      }

      if(minDist > maxMin)
      {
         maxMin = minDist;
         maxVal = candidate;
      }
   }
   return candidate;
}
```

In Scala:

```
def maxmin(l: Seq[Int], size: Int): Seq[Int] =
{
  def more(selected: Seq[Int], reminder: Seq[Int], size: Int): Seq[Int] =
  {
     if(size == 0) selected
     else
     {
        val max = reminder.maxBy(x => selected.map(y => math.abs(y - x)).min)
        more(selected :+ max, reminder diff Seq(max), size-1)
     }
  }

  more(Seq(l.head), l.tail, size-1)
}
```

I did not checked the Java code, but the Scala one seems OK. Otherwise, please provide a counter-example because that probably means I not understood the problem.

Comment: A heroic effort but I am afraid this doesn't answer the question asked.  The OP is specifically asking for a solution done with Dynamic Programming techniques, although I must admit, I do not understand the problem as stated here.